# get SQL join derived table to show a single row

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT products.id
    , products.Name
    , products_orders.productQty
FROM orders
JOIN products_orders
ON orders.id = products_orders.order_id
JOIN products
ON products_orders.product_id = products.id
WHERE orders.id = @OrderId;
```

@OrderId = 7, and I have a product ID too, and ultimately I'm trying to find the quantity of a single product in an order.

Currently this returns a table like this:

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | Name      | productQty |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  1 | sourdough |          2 |
|  3 | Ciabatta  |          3 |
+----+-----------+------------+
```

This is each item in the order and its quantity, but i'm just trying to find a single item based on the ID in the first column there.

Is there a way to whittle this table down to show ONLY the item and its quantity that I'm interested in?

For example,

If order.id = 7, and product.id = 3 (for the ciabatta, it's its foreign id key)
I'd like to return a derived table that looks like this, but I don't know how to write the query:

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | Name      | productQty |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  3 | Ciabatta  |          3 |
+----+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: In SQL, a _derived table_ is a sub-query in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with adding `AND products.id = @ProductId` to the query?  It would something like

```
SELECT products.id
    , products.Name
    , products_orders.productQty
FROM orders
JOIN products_orders
ON orders.id = products_orders.order_id
JOIN products
ON products_orders.product_id = products.id
WHERE orders.id = @OrderId
AND products.id = @ProductID;
```

Comment: oh, I just don't know SQL very well at all :( I'll try that out now.

Comment: This worked! Thank you! I'll mark it as an answer as soon as I am able to.